# php multidimensional array add number

Tags: php, arrays

I am getting form data like this from form post

```
Array
(
    [instagram] => dsaadsasd
    [facebook] => 12esda
)
```

I have to arrange data like these but i couldnt solve

```
 Array
([0]=>Array(
    [name] => instagram
    [data] => dsaadsasd)

 [1]=>Array(
    [name] => facebook
    [data] => 12esda)
```

Comment: what you are suggesting is not valid JSON.

Comment: @DirkJ.Faber Pls check again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP your array looks like this:

```
$array = ['instagram' => 'dsaadsasd', 'facebook' => '12esda'];
```

Now to change this data into your desired array you can use a [forEach loop](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php), like so:

```
$newArray = [];
forEach($array as $key => $value){
$newArray[] = ["name" => $key, "data" => $value];
}
```

What this does is it creates an new array that for each of the items in your original array creates another array in your new array. Here's also a [live example](https://3v4l.org/kL0j2).

Comment: before i can list data 'foreach($info as $key => $val){' but now how can list only 'name'?

Comment: @Can1, I'm sorry but I do not understand what you mean. If you want to access any of the data "below", you can use `$newArray[0]["data"]` (the `0` is for the first item of the array)